# Macbook pro Retina Display, Webcam doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, webcam, macbook-pro

Well i have a Macbook pro retina display running Ubuntu 16.04, i was trying the webcam on my computer and realized that it wasn't working, i don't know if is due to some missing drivers or anything else. 
the only message i get from cheese was: "no device found" i also tried a few programs from Ubuntu Software, and skype. But non of them seems to fix the problem.

Comment: I haven't gotten these working in Ubuntu, at least following [these community guides](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro).  Interested to see if there is a new solution. May want to add the output of `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name` to your question.

Comment: Try guvcview, it seems to work with more cameras.